# Bash: How to read lines from a txt file, identify and remove duplicates by column value

Tags: linux, bash, line, grouping

I'm writing a Bash script, in which I'm collecting data from some logfiles, removing the duplicate values, sort it by username and storing the output in the output.txt.
What I would like to do next, is to read the output.txt line by line and whenever the username appears more than once, to create a new line which will have data from both lines.

The purpose of this, is to send an email to the user ONLY ONCE and inform him that he can't use this feature on this server.

I don't know if I'm explaining it well..
For example see below the output.txt

**output.txt**

> 13:49:19 DENIED: "Software_1" **UserA** serv7 (Can't run this feature. )
>    13:49:19 DENIED: "Software_2" **UserA** serv7 (Can't run this feature. )
>    15:09:14 DENIED: "Software_3" **UserB** serv5 (Can't run this feature. )
>    15:09:15 DENIED: "Software_4" **UserB** serv5 (Can't run this feature. )
>    17:20:43 DENIED: "Software_3" **UserC** serv5 (Can't run this feature. )
>    17:20:43 DENIED: "Software_5" **UserC** serv8 (Can't run this feature. )

**expected result**

> Software_1, Software_2, **UserA** serv7 (Can't run this feature. )
>    Software_3, Software_4, **UserB** serv5 (Can't run this feature. )
>    Software_3, Software_5, **UserC** serv5, serv8  (Can't run this feature. )

Can someone suggest a solution and explain how it's working?

Comment: Presumably, "Software 1" etc. isn't really what you have in output.txt? If the lengths, number of words etc. are different it would be useful to show that.

Comment: @TomFenech yes, all of the names are fictional, but for the software column, i updated my description.
 All the software names have underscores instead of spaces

Answer (score 1):

process.awk:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
NF {
     sft[$4] = sft[$4] $3 ", ";
     if (!(srv[$4] ~ $5))
         srv[$4] = srv[$4] $5 ", ";
     mesg[$4] = $6 " " $7 " " $8 " " $9 " " $10
}

END {
    for (user in sft) {
        gsub("\"", "", sft[user]);
        print  sft[user], user, srv[user], mesg[user];
    }
}
```

This AWK script checks if a line is not blank (using the number of fields built-in variable, NF). If so, it maintains an array for software and server, indexing them by the user field. For each user type, it appends the server and software associated to it. This happens for each line.

When all the lines in the input file is done processing, in the `END` pattern, it iterates over all the entries in the software array printing the associated software, users, servers and the message.

To run it

```
awk -f process.awk output.txt
```

Comment: @TomFenech i mostly care to group the softwares and the servers :)

Comment: i created a file in which i pasted your code and i entered the run command in my script. When i'm trying to run my script i'm getting  awk: can't open process.awk
Do you know why?

Comment: Make sure you name the file _process.awk_ and save it under the same directory as the bash script you call it from.

Comment: I did it but now i have the following 2 errors

Both are in the process.awk

awk: syntax error near line 3
awk: bailing out near line 3

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat userlog_unparsed.log
13:49:19 DENIED: "Software_1" UserA serv7 (Can't run this feature. )
13:49:19 DENIED: "Software_2" UserA serv7 (Can't run this feature. )
15:09:14 DENIED: "Software_3" UserB serv5 (Can't run this feature. )
15:09:15 DENIED: "Software_4" UserB serv5 (Can't run this feature. )
17:20:43 DENIED: "Software_3" UserC serv5 (Can't run this feature. )
17:20:43 DENIED: "Software_5" UserC serv8 (Can't run this feature. )


$ awk '
     { sws[$4][$3]++; srvs[$4][$5]++; }
     END{
         for(user in sws){
             swuser="";srvuser="";
             for(sw in sws[user]){swuser=swuser","sw}
             for(srv in srvs[user]){srvuser=srvuser","srv};
             print substr(swuser,2) ", " user ", " substr(srvuser,2);
         }
     }' userlog_unparsed.log

"Software_2","Software_1", UserA, serv7
"Software_3","Software_4", UserB, serv5
"Software_3","Software_5", UserC, serv5,serv8
```

Explanation:

1. Record all the users & their softwares, servers.
2. At the end, loop through all of them, & append the users, their respective servers & softwares. & print them.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this relies on GNU awk.

Comment: @anishsane Thank you for your solution. Just to mention that the software column doesn't have spaces, but underscores so you can count it as one column

Comment: gawk: not found :/
I'm running SunOS 5.8 sun4u